# Excel 2010 Solver: Decision Variables in Two Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am using the Excel 2010 solver to do some optimizations. Everything is running well except that I would like to run the solver to find a solution such that my decision variables, $A$1:$A$10, are either between 5.1 and 15.3 or between -5.1 and -15.3. I have tried a number of approaches and cannot figure out how to set the constraints. The positive part is OK,

```
 $A$1:$A$10 >= 5.1
 $A$1:$A$10 <= 15.3
```

It is the negative range that I am having difficulty with. I have tried

```
 -$A$1:$A$10 >= 5.1
 -$A$1:$A$10 <= 15.3
```

and even

```
 ABS($A$1:$A$10) >= 5.1
 ABS($A$1:$A$10) <= 15.3
```

but it does not work. I have searched on the net but cannot seem to find anything to help. Is this possible to do, and if so, how would I do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear... can you give some example values for A1:A10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
$A$1:$A$10 <= -5.1
$A$1:$A$10 >= -15.3
```

### Edit:

Create a cell with array formula (hit Ctrl-Enter when finished editing)

```
=SUM(NOT(ABS($A$1:$A$10)<=15.3)+NOT(ABS($A$1:$A$10)>=5.1))
```

and constrain the cell to zero.

### Edit2:

If A1:A10 are your decision variables then I recommend doing a transformation on the cells. There's a number of options here but the most obvious is a piecewise linear function:

```
A1=IF(B1<0.5,B1*((10.2)/0.5) - 15.3,(B1 - 0.5)*((10.2)/0.5) + 5.1 )
```

This transforms cell A1 to a value ABS(A1) <= 15.3 && ABS(A1) >= 5.1 given B1 <= 1 && B1 >= 0. So your new decision variables would be B1:B10 with constraint B1:B10>=0 and B1:B10<=1.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this will not work. I need each cell value to be 5.1 <= cell value <= 15.3 OR -15.3 <= cell value <= -5.1.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it valid to have cell A1 = 6 and A2 = -6 or do they all need to be the same sign?

Comment: The signs can vary. They don't need to be the same sign. I am trying your formula.

Comment: The formula give #VALUE in the cell and the solver gives error stating that all variables must be bounded; i.e. have both upper and lower bounds.

Comment: Are you sure it's entered as an array formula? If you click on the cell is it surrounded with curly braces?

Comment: Yes. It is an array formula.

Comment: Hm, i've tested it on Excel 2010, not sure why you're getting a VALUE error.... How about just creating a new cell range which is the absolute value of A1:A10 and set contraints on that range?

Comment: These cells are the decision variables. Right now I have them set at 0% and still have the Value error. Also the solver wants upper and lower constraints on this cell. Not sure how to do it if we're constraining it to 0.

Comment: The second edit is interesting but ultimately I need the A values. Will this give me the A values?

Comment: Yes, the rest of your sheet still depends on A1:A10 and these values will be within your bounds. The solver would be modifying cells B1:B10 but once it converges you'd look at column A to get your true optimal inputs.

Comment: I will try this out. But shouldn't it be reversed? That is B1=IF(A1<0.5 ...

Comment: I can see how this will work as indicated but I need to recover the actual A values with their signs rather than their absolute values. Any ideas?

Comment: It's A1 = IF(B1<0.5... so that you don't need to up date the rest of your sheet. You'll recover the A values with their sign since when B1 = 0 then A1 = -15.3 and when B1 = 0.499999 A1 = -3.1. Meanwhile when B1 =0.5 A1=3.1 and when B1=1 A1 = 15.3.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it out but it is late here now so I will do this tomorrow morning. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: It worked beautifully. Thank you VERY much for the insight. I did not even know how to approach this but your example showed me how it is possible and I am truly grateful.